# Can Textures be added to simple objects from my own source?

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If I build a simple object such as a cylinder or a box I can add texture from the gazebo.material file e.g.:

```
     <script>
        <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
        <name>Gazebo/CeilingTiled</name>
      </script>
```

And this is matched with the block from the gazebo.material file:

material Gazebo/CeilingTiled
{
receive_shadows on

technique
{
pass
{
ambient 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.000000

```
  texture_unit
  {
    texture ceiling_tiled.jpg
  }
}
```

}
}

... and then I can get a nice textured and properly lit object in Gazebo.

But this seems to be limited to just the materials in this particular file - about 20 of them. How can I specify my own .material file to map my own texture onto the object model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1500/can-textures-be-added-to-simple-objects-from-my-own-source?/) by [techy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/227/techy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So there's two ways (that I know of) that you can do this:

- Within the model directory: create a materials/scripts and materials/textures directory in the directory of the corresponding model and put the texture into materials/textures and the corresponding *.material into materials/scripts ... have a look at your very own [`brick_box_3x1x3`](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/03ba6e062bdcbff75832d56577cae44886f540d1/brick_box_3x1x3?at=default) for example. ;)
- If you want to specify materials that can be used by multiple models you can create a folder "media" that, again, contains "materials/scripts" and "materials/textures" as sub-directories and then add the directory that your "media" directory is part of to your `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`. So for example with the default setup you have a "`/usr/local/share/gazebo-1.4/media`" directory (compiled from source, debian package installation would be in `/usr/share/...`) and "`/usr/local/share/gazebo-1.4`" is in the `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`. To add your own materials you simply create a "`<my_package>/media/materials/`" directory with the desired scripts and textures and add "`<my_package>`" to the `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3